# Browser load top bottom or bottom top?

Tags: html, css, browser

I was told once either a browser loads from top to bottom OR does it load from bottom to top?  Or was I told a css file reads from  bottom to top?

I was wondering because some one asked me and I said a browser loads from bottom to top.   Maybe I was referring to CSS. Maybe it reads from bottom to top.  I've search on Google but can't find anything that tells me for sure.

Comment: Can you elaborate the question more specific? What do you mean by browser load? Rendering of HTML in a browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be confusing *loading* with *rendering*. The browser loads the webpage and reads it from top to bottom like any other program. In addition, it loads and parses styles from top to bottom.

As a result of this, a browser kind of *renders as it goes*, but on most websites and most internet connections this is not noticeable (i.e. the whole page seems to render at once). Styles are applied after the main html is rendered. This is why sometimes elements (and fonts) will change a split second after you first see the page.

Comment: Then why in a page when multiple css styles are in the head <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css" media="screen" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles2.css" media="screen" /> the bottom takes precedence over the top styles?

Comment: In other words, mystyles2.css takes precedence over mystyles.css.  And mystyles2.css is under mystyles.css.  I've proven this by using a template with 3 stylesheets.  I created custom.css.  I used the same styles as in the original stylesheets.  I changed colors and and many other things.  Custom.css is overriding the original styles.   For example, original.css, original2.css, and custom.css < this is the order between the head tags.  Custom.css has changed the original styles.

Comment: @user5319102 read up on the CSS priority scheme: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#CSS_Priority_scheme_.28highest_to_lowest.29
Your comment relates to #6 - Rule order - Last rule declaration has a higher priority

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks